# Including File Upload in Razor Form View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC 3, VB.NET. I have a form in my app that gets basic information from the user and then allows them to upload a resume. I am accomplishing this right now by using a redirect to a different form that's only purpose is to select the file for uploading and then submit it.. Sloppy in my opinion.. I have tried to do it from the same form but the file is being lost on submit.. While I am not certain of it I believe it is because I am not using the correct syntax in the form to handle the file... Below is the View so far and then the controller post function..

```
@ModelType xxxxxxxx.courseproposal
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Course Proposal"
End Code
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">         </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Using Html.BeginForm()
@Html.ValidationSummary(True)
@<fieldset>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Presenter 1</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td>Email Address</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Name_First1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Name_First1)</th>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Name_Last1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Name_Last1)</th>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Title_1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Title_1)</th>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.phone_number1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.phone_number1)</th>
        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.email_address1) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.email_address1)</th>
         <th>@Html.Label("file","Filename:")<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />  </th>
    </tr>
</table> 

<div id="sidebar3">

 <p>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Course Proposal" />
 </p>

 <p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </p>
 </div>

</fieldset>
End Using
```

And the post Function is like this:

```
   <AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
    Function CourseProposal(ByVal courseprop As courseproposal) As ActionResult
        courseprop.conf_Number = _AnnualNumber
        db.courseproposals.AddObject(courseprop)
        db.SaveChanges()
        _id = courseprop.idCourseProposal
        Dim _filename As String = String.Empty
        For Each File As String In Request.Files
            Dim hpf As HttpPostedFileBase = TryCast(Request.Files(File), HttpPostedFileBase)
            If hpf.ContentLength = 0 Then
                Continue For
            End If
            Dim savedfileName As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\CoursePropResumes\" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)
            hpf.SaveAs(savedfileName)
            _filename = hpf.FileName
        Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Try

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

**EDIT**: That of course is for C#. In VB it should read

```
Html.BeginForm(Nothing, Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With { .enctype="multipart/form-data"})
```

Comment: I edited it as follows:  @Using Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data"}) What are the null, null params for VB flags them saying "Not Declared"

Comment: Sorry, not so strong with VB. The full syntax is `Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})` but in C# you can avoid stating the action and the controller by passing null to both values.

Comment: I fixed the syntax. But the file is still not being returned to the controller... It should show up in the HttpPostedFileBase I but there is nothing there..

Comment: Can you check what is being POSTed with FireBug or similar tool? It should read somewhere

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="..."
Content-Type: ...`

Comment: -----------------------------41184676334 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="log.txt" Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: Ok the file is POSTed. Is the `Request.Files` collection empty?

Comment: I assume the Request.Files collection is empty because Its saving the file somehow where it should go, but It is never hitting the break point that I have put in the For Each Loop at the Dim hpf as HttpPostedFileBase..... Any ideas as to why this might be??

Comment: It was just the route value on the html.beginform.... Thanks much for the help...