# File not uploading to catalog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to upload a file to a folder with BeginForm(). I am creating a scaffold item and my view looks as follows:

```
@model Blog.Models.Resource

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Resources", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart / form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Resource</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <!---Name-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResourceName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResourceName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResourceName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <!---Resource-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />


        <!---Text-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My model is as follows:

```
  public class Resource
    {

        [Key]
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }

        public string ResourceName { get; set; }

        public string Item { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

    }
```

My Action is as follows:

```
 // GET: /Resources/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Resources/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Resource resource, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            //verify file that file exist
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //get filename
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                //store file in speficied folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Catalog/Uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Resources.Add(resource);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(resource);
        }
```

I have been looking around on other posts and my situation is almost as described in this post but I do include `{enctype = "multipart / form-data"}`. However for me it does not work:

[ASP.NET MVC File-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830266/asp-net-mvc-file-upload)

While the other data is saved onto the database the file is not uploaded to the specified folder.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it folder permissions problem? do you get any errors?

Comment: @markpsmith Well it was as mentioned by Steven and Inanikian but in addition, just as Steven suggested, I had some spaces in my encoding type rendering it useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file not being saved would lead me to believe it is null. Two things I would try:

1. Try no spaces on the `enctype`. So it would be `multipart/form-data`.
2. Make the name of your file upload match the `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter on your action. So change the `<input type="file" name="FileUpload1" />` to `<input type="file" name="file" />`. That could help the model binder do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because the `name` of the input file doesn't match with the `HttpPostedFileBase` variable name .
So you should have something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Resource resource, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload1)
    {
        //verify file that file exist
        if (fFileUpload1 != null && FileUpload1.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //get filename
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            //store file in speficied folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Catalog/Uploads"), fileName);
           FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Resources.Add(resource);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(resource);
    }
```